# Can I transfer my dota2 account invite to another account?

Tags: steam, dota-2

Now I have two steam account, bombess and bombless. I received a dota2 account invite email and click the link I received when I was using my steam account bombess. So now bombess got the gift. But I actually want to play dota2 with the account bombless. What can I do now? Do I *have to* play with my account bombess now or is it possible to tranfer that invite to my bombless steam account?

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is possible to transfer gifts (in case you haven't activated them by mistake).

- Make friends between the 2 accounts(so you can simply select from friends list when sending gift)
- Go to "My Profile" > "My Inventory"
- Select "Steam" from the list of games and in bottom grid you should see you Dota 2 gift,select it and click "Send gift..."
- Select "Send my gift directly through Steam" and under there select your other account from the friend list.
- Log in to your second account and activate the gift.

Now you can also use the **[steam trade offers](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2178-QGJV-0708)** in case you have issues with direct gifting.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it:

**The first one described by [Arremer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90269/8350):**

> - Make friends between the 2 accounts(so you can simply select from friends list when sending gift)
> - Go to "My Profile" > "My Inventory"
> - Select "Steam" from the list of games and in bottom grid you should see you Dota 2 gift,select it and click "Send gift..."
> - Select "Send my gift directly through Steam" and under there select your other account from the friend list.
> - Log in to your second account and activate the gift.

**The Second one (faster but require 2 computers):**

- Start both of your steam accounts on 2 different computer
- Start a chat between both of your accounts and proceed to an item exchange
- Dota 2 invitation are tradable items so you'll be able to give them directly through the trade window